# django after redirect adding form.errors to messages doesn't appear in template?

Tags: python, django

after redirect adding form.errors to messages if form not valid , form.errors doesn't appear in template

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
@user_passes_test(user_is_patient_check, login_url='login')
def changePasswordPatient(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user,request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user=form.save()           
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user) 
            messages.success(request,'Şifreniz başarıyla güncellendi!')
            return redirect("changePasswordPatient")
        else:
            messages.error(request,form.errors,extra_tags="invalidchangepassword")
            return redirect("changePasswordPatient")   # this part 

    form=PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
    context={
        "form":form,
        "which_active":"passwordchange"
    }
    return render(request,"change-password.html",context)
```

but when I changed if form not valid part like using this(render method).Form errors showing in template.But in this method when I refresh page errors messages still showing.Can anyone help me to fix that?

```
if form.is_valid():
            user=form.save()           
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)  # Important!
            messages.success(request,'Şifreniz başarıyla güncellendi!')
            return redirect("changePasswordPatient")
        else:
            messages.error(request,form.errors,extra_tags="invalidchangepassword")
            return render(request,"change-password.html",{"form":form,"which_active":"passwordchange"})
```

change-password.html

```
{% if form.errors %}
                 {% for field in form %}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <center><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></center>
                                                     </div>
                                                     {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <center><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></center>
                                                     </div>
                {% endfor %}
                                     
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may edit your `redirect` into the following:

```
messages.error(request,form.errors,extra_tags="invalidchangepassword")
form=PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
return redirect("changePasswordPatient", {"form":form})   # this part
```

Comment: I modified this part as you say,but after that there is an error like that:      NoReverseMatch at /changePasswordPatient
Reverse for 'changePasswordPatient' with arguments '({'form': <PasswordChangeForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(old_password;new_password1;new_password2)>},)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['changePasswordPatient$']

Comment: Hi, @MuhammetAydoğan I have amended my answer, can you please try again